# iBeacons: how reduce Irregular signal?

Tags: ibeacon

I intend to create a indoor app and i have problem with the irregular response of the ibeacons.

If i have 9 ibeacons sometimes the response of this ibeacons is very random:

Example:

- The yellow circle is the user with the iphone.
- The blue circle with number is the result of calculate the radius of 3 ibeacons.
- The numbers 5002-5003-5004 is the ibeacon number and physic position.

In this example sometimes the first ibeacon detected is 5004 then 5005 then 5008 and  again 5005 etc.

Example Image of the problem

[image]

Any suggestion for reduce this irregular signal?

P.D: All the ibeacons have set TxPower in -12 DBM and interval in 250ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **set your expectations appropriately** when ranging for beacons.  **Distance estimates** are based on bluetooth signal strength measurements which are **inherently noisy** and affected by signal multipath, attenuation from obstructions (including the human body) and even phone orientation.  While it is possible to reliably tell if a beacon is within a meter of a mobile device vs. 5 meters or more away, it simply is not possible to reliably determine exactly how far it is away.

That said, there are several things you can do to improve the accuracy of your distance estimates:

1. **Increase your advertising frequency** as much as possible.  This helps because it gives you more statistical samples of signal strength to average over a time interval.  The 250 ms mentioned in the question is way too low.  You want to advertise at least every 100 ms, and more if possible.
2. **Increase the transmitter power** as much as possible.  This will give you a higher signal to noise ratio, so more accurate estimates.
3. Be sure you **re-calibrate** after adjusting the transmitter power as suggested in (2).
4. **Check the antenna pattern** of your beacons.  Some beacons transmit more weakly at certain angles.  Few manufacturers publish antenna patterns, but you can do a rough job of measuring the pattern by doing a one meter calibration on each compass point.  If you find a particularly weak or strong side of your beacon, point it away from the area you need to be getting a consistent signal.

Following the above steps won't eliminate the inherent accuracy limitations of ranging for bluetooth beacons.  But they will help give you as good of results as you can get.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Points to consider before positioning the beacons

**1. Beacons Settings**

Transmission power, Advertisement interval should be increased for better accuracy, though it reduces the life of the beacon.

**2. Beacons Placements**

Beacon's signal should collide each other. In the reference Image each Bluetooth icon refers the beacon and each circle refers the range of each beacon. beacon's signal should collide each other.

For greater location accuracy results,  Beacons needs to be placed on the walls at around 2m height.

[image: Beacon's placements]